# Enabling panel when php gets executed unless its hidden

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I using php to display result to my page and I did a bit of styling using bootstrap

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <?php    
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //check if form was submitted
         include "assets/backend/newsletter.php";
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

Even the php code is not executed I can see the blank panel.
How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image for reference.][1]I think on ur case this makes way much more sens then what are u doing up there:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?>
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">  
 <?php include "assets/backend/newsletter.php"; ?>
</div>
<?php}?>
```

This way if the form was submitted the panel will appear if not submitted the panel will not be visible.

```
footer.php
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <?php    
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> ';
           include 'assets/backend/newsletter.php';
           echo '</div>';
       }
        ?>
    </div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#222222">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:15px;
            margin-bottom:15px">
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#f3f6f9">
                <img src="images/pc%20logo.png" width="80px" height="80px">
                <h4 >
                    PLACEMENT  
                    <cell style="font-weight:bold">CELL</cell>
                </h4>
                <p>Nehru Nagar, Ring Road <br>New Delhi <br>
                    Ph :(+91) 964 328 0581<br>
                    Email : placements.pgdav@gmail.com
                </p>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pgdavplacements">  <img src="images/f.png" height="30px" width="30px" >
                </a>
                <img src="images/i.png" height="30px" width="30px">
                <img src="images/linkedin.png" height="30px" width="30px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#f3f6f9;
                padding-top:30px">
                <h4>Subscribe to Our Newsletter</h4>
                <form action=" " method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text"
                            id="inputemail" name="email_newsletter" placeholder="Your Email ID">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="subscribe">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#f3f6f9;
                padding-top:29px">
                <h4>Links</h4>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutcell.php">About Cell</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#f3f6f9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container" style="padding-top:7px">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">© All the Rights Reserved with Placement Cell</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align:right"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bhanukrsingh/">Developed By Bhanu Singh</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

or this:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <?php    
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ ?>
         <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> 
          <?php 
           include 'assets/backend/newsletter.php';
           ?>
           </div>
       <?php
       }
        ?>
    </div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#222222">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:15px;
            margin-bottom:15px">
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#f3f6f9">
                <img src="images/pc%20logo.png" width="80px" height="80px">
                <h4 >
                    PLACEMENT  
                    <cell style="font-weight:bold">CELL</cell>
                </h4>
                <p>Nehru Nagar, Ring Road <br>New Delhi <br>
                    Ph :(+91) 964 328 0581<br>
                    Email : placements.pgdav@gmail.com
                </p>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pgdavplacements">  <img src="images/f.png" height="30px" width="30px" >
                </a>
                <img src="images/i.png" height="30px" width="30px">
                <img src="images/linkedin.png" height="30px" width="30px">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#f3f6f9;
                padding-top:30px">
                <h4>Subscribe to Our Newsletter</h4>
                <form action=" " method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text"
                            id="inputemail" name="email_newsletter" placeholder="Your Email ID">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="subscribe">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#f3f6f9;
                padding-top:29px">
                <h4>Links</h4>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutcell.php">About Cell</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Registration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#f3f6f9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container" style="padding-top:7px">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">© All the Rights Reserved with Placement Cell</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align:right"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bhanukrsingh/">Developed By Bhanu Singh</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

tested both options are workin;

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\PlacementCell\assets\php\footer.php on line
I got an error.

Comment: @Bhanusingh  share footer.php

Comment: check Now @Leo_kelmendi

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\PlacementCell\assets\php\footer.php on line 64

Comment: @Bhanusingh close the 'a' tag here         <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="text-align:right"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bhanukrsingh/">Developed By Bhanu Singh</a></div>

Comment: Done :) But that error is still there. Is there any other way I can make this thing happen.

Comment: I did that changes and it did not help.

Comment: @Bhanusingh remove the php part entirely and see if u are still getting the error

Comment: Added image for reference. @Leo_Kelmendi

Comment: Nah its the same. I can't understand how this would help?